Where did Kyle Reese get the hacksaw in The Terminator?
Towards the beginning of The Terminator (1984), Kyle Reese boosts a shotgun from a cop car.  Later, he saws off the stock with a hacksaw. Where did he get the hacksaw?  (The rest of what he and Arnold get to get started in town seems to be well explained; clothes, weapons, vehicles, etc.)

According to the official novelisation by Randall Frakes, Reese found the hacksaw blade in a bin in an alley behind an auto repair shop on Wilshire Boulevard.

Reese was moving along the wall of a particularly nasty stretch of alley behind Gajewski's Foreign Auto Repair on Wilshire—"Guaranteed to put the bite back in your bug!"—when the roar of an engine behind him erupted from his rear. Cover! Cover! Cover! Reese's body was moving before his brain kicked in. He leaped to the far side of a pile of trash cans stacked against the decomposing brick, and rolling, burrowed his way behind them. A delivery truck had tumbled into the alley's entrance a little too fast, tires screeching on the wet pavement as the half-asleep driver jumped
on the brake to avoid the wall. Reese chambered a round into the shotgun, his nerves jangling like high-wire tension cables, and brought it up as the delivery truck heaved and groaned past. Slowly, he released the pressure building up on the trigger and lowered the shotgun. The sleepy driver
never saw Reese and would never know that he had been only a hairbreadth away from having his wife raise their children alone.
Reese's heart was pumping loudly. He glanced up at the tiny slit of sky beyond the rim of buildings surrounding him. It was light.
No good staying in the alleys anymore, Reese thought. Got to blend with the population. He had been carrying the long shotgun under his raincoat, held between his arm and side, but that wouldn't pass with the natives in full daylight. Time to adapt the weapon to street-fighting mode.
He rummaged through the trash bin beside him—dead auto parts, bits of tubing, and greasy splinters of metal. Then he found what he was looking for, a rusty but usable hacksaw blade. Reese couldn't understand why so much perfectly good material was thrown away here. He could have built a combat carrier out of what he found in one trash bin.
Reese put the blade to the shotgun's stock, just behind the trigger housing, leaving enough wood to act as a makeshift pistol grip. He dug deeper into the bin but ran out of luck; nothing to make a sling with.
It was on the fourth try, in one of the bins farther down the wall, that he found a fraying piece of rope. Tying one end to the weapon's shortened stock, Reese made himself a sliding shoulder rig. When the time came, he could bring the weapon up smooth and fast. And the concealment was excellent. He'd have to be searched before anyone would notice he was armed. But by then they'd already know.
The Terminator (novel by Randall Frakes)

The flow of the narration implies that it's the same alley he's in when he modifies the shotgun; we see him crouching beside a row of bins in that scene. They just didn't show the parts with him rummaging through the bins.


The Terminator (1984)

